# Slamdata Issue in Ubuntu (14.04.3 LTS) AWS Bitnami instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, slamdata

There isn't any error on installation and on startup I get the below message :

Server started listening on port 20223

Failed to open browser, please navigate to http://localhost:20223/

But the server is instance is not reachable @ http://localhost:20223/ or 
http://localhost:20223/slamdata/index.html

netstat -pnlt show the server is up & listening to port

tcp6       0      0 :::20223                :::*                    LISTEN      24564/java

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

This was initially caused by a threading issue that was identified and resolved.  If a user's virtual (or physical) environment had only one CPU available then the Scalaz executor might hang.  It should not matter how many CPUs a server has now.  See [here](https://slamdata.atlassian.net/browse/SD-1574) for SD-1574 in JIRA.

Recent versions of SlamData (i.e. late April 2016 and newer) do not have this problem.